# Style invalid <select> using :invalid

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a `<select>`:

```css
select:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select required>
  <option disabled selected>- please choose -</option>
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

Unfortunately the disabled select is not marked red.

Any idea?

### It's not the option I like to style, I like to style the select!

Comment: It’s unclear what result you expect. `- please choose -` is red on the select box for me (Firefox 61, Arch Linux, Gnome).

Comment: @Xufox Ah firefox does not have this problem ;)

Comment: You should be aware that none of the solutions provided will work in Safari or Chrome on Mac.

Comment: @Turnip indeed. Do you know any way to make this work on Safari?

Comment: @Grim if you use the feature to mimic gray placeholder on input fields, then Firefox will render both colors differently for whatever reason. At least on Firefox dev edition on Mac.

Comment: @Mig Thank you for the information about mac. Not sure what caused the different behaviour. Could you elaborate how the select behaves on phones?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to specify **`value=""`** for the first option. Without `value=""`, the value of an option is implicitly equal to its *text content*, meaning it fulfils the `required` constraint.

Demo:

```css
select:invalid { color: red; }
```

```html
<select required>
  <option disabled value="" selected>- please choose -</option>
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

The above will make the **select + all options** red until a value has been chosen.

If you want the **options** to *always* be black, just extend the CSS a little:

```css
select:invalid { color: red; }
select option { color: black; }
```

```html
<select required>
  <option disabled value="" selected>- please choose -</option>
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I used `value` without `=""`. I hope it looks more *invalid* than a empty value.

Comment: As @Turnip mentioned in the question comments, this does not work on Safari+Mac though.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `option:disabled`.

```css
select option:disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select required>
  <option disabled selected>- please choose -</option>
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You style the option, i need to style the select.

Comment: @PeterRader your select is not disabled. Your first option is disabled. So what exactly do you want: to paint the whole select red (with all the options inside it, which user could change and they still be painted red), or just to make paint the select red when the disabled option is chosen (and in other cases leave select white), or what?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.choose_elements{
    background-color : red;
}
.elements{
    background-color : white;
}
```

```html
<select required 
    onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className" 
    class="choose_elements">
    <option value="0" class="choose_elements">- please choose -</option>
    <option value="1" class = "elements">A</option>
    <option value="2" class = "elements">B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Select remains red if I choose valid option. A select having a valid option selected is not invalid anymore. If your browser gives different output, please write the browser in the comments.

Comment: This is better, but if I have a `<input type="reset" />` in the form it does not work.